# Javascript: regex escaped space

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a directory with space on unix, so the space is backslashed. And I need to replace the backslashed space with semicolon. Tried multiple regex'es but not able to find the answer

```
var str = '/test\ space/a.sh -pqr';
```

So I am looking to get this after the replace /test;space/a.sh -pqr

```
console.log("replace: ", str.replace(/\\\s+/g, ";")); //This one doesn't work, (formatting is taking out one backslash)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is correct.

It's your example string that is incorrect - the `\` is not properly escaped:

```
var str = '/test\\ space/a.sh -pqr';
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9A5n/) and read more [special characters in JavaScript strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Comment: the original string is correct because the space is backslashed. There is no 'backslash' in the directory name. To test, create a directory in linux, mkdir "test space". and now if you do cd te and press tab, you will get the same string as the original string.

Comment: I understand that it is correct as it is displayed. But for a JavaScript string to properly store a literal backslash you need to escape it. Output `str`, you should see what I mean.